# Cant select both the character and bones for rigging

Tags: blender, 3d-modelling

I am trying to rig a character in blender. So after I created my bones, I pressed pose mode. After following a tutorial I suppose to select the character then select the bones and parent them with weights. First time I tried it worked but I messed up later and ctr+z to try again, but this time it doesn't work. When I select the character and go on to select the bone my character gets deselected and and I cant parent them anymore. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>-clicking an object will add or remove an object to/from the current selection. If you miss the armature, the <kbd>Shift</kbd>-click will deselect the mesh.

If you are having trouble selecting items in the 3D view, you may find it easier to use the [outliner](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/outliner.html). In the outliner you want to click on the object name or icon, if you click to the side, the line will be highlighted which is an outliner selection, not a 3D view selection.

Also in the outliner, you will see a little arrow cursor for each item, if this is dimmed it means the item is not selectable in the 3D view.

[image: view of the outliner]